# Client not responding - multi thread in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

I am trying to make 2 threads. One will always be listening and second one will check if the server is listening or not.

```
Host='127.0.0.1'
Port= 5555
threads=[]
threads2=[]

def server() :
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.bind((Host, Port)) 
        while 1:
            print("listen() ") 
            s.listen() 
            conn, address= s. accept() 
            with conn:
                print(" Connected by", address) 
                while True:

                   data=conn.recv(1024) 
                   print("from caller", representing(data)) 


def client () :
    s= socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
    try:
        s.bind(('127.0.0.1', 5555)) 
    except socket.error as e:
        if e.errno==errno.EADDRINUSE:
            print("port in use") 
        else:
            print("connected")  
    s.close() 



served = threading.Thread(target=server) 
threads.append(served) 
served.start() 
print("started the server thread") 
time.sleep(2) 
click =threading.Thread(target=client) 
threads2.append(click) 
click.start() 
print("click started")
```

I am getting the below output

```
started the server thread
listen() 
click started
```

And after this it doesnt show anything.

Comment: What do you expect to happen ?

Comment: I want the second thread to print if it was able to connect to thread 1 or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to `bind` the socket in both the server and the client. You can only `bind` once. (See the [Python documentation on this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.bind]).

Instead, for the client, you should use `connect`:

```py
def client () :
    s= socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
    try:
        # use s.connect instead of s.bind
        s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 5555)) 
    except socket.error as e:
        if e.errno==errno.EADDRINUSE:
            print("port in use") 
        else:
            print("connected")  
    s.close()
```